# Why record cannot get deleted using JDBC Sink Connector in Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

**my sink properties :**

```
{
  "name": "jdbc-oracle",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "orders",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.1.2.3:1071/orac",
    "connection.user": "ersin",
    "connection.password": "ersin!",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "delete.enabled": "true",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "pk.fields": "id",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "plugin.path": "/home/ersin/confluent-5.4.1/share/java/",
    "name": "jdbc-oracle"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "connector": "jdbc-oracle",
      "task": 0
    }
  ],
  "type": "sink"
}
```

**my connect-avro-distributed.properties**   :

```
bootstrap.servers=10.0.0.0:9092

group.id=connect-cluster

key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://10.0.0.0:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://10.0.0.0:8081

config.storage.topic=connect-configs
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
status.storage.topic=connect-statuses

config.storage.replication.factor=1
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.replication.factor=1

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

**I send data like this:**

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer \
  --broker-list 10.0.0.0:9092 --topic orders \
  --property parse.key="true" \
  --property key.schema='{"type":"record","name":"key_schema","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"int"}]}' \
  --property key.separator="$" \
  --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"id","type":["null","int"],"default": null},{"name":"product","type": ["null","string"],"default": null}, {"name":"quantity", "type":  ["null","int"],"default": null}, {"name":"price","type":  ["null","int"],"default": null}]}' \
  --property schema.registry.url=http://10.0.0.0:8081
```

**I can insert or update data on oracle like this**

```
{"id":3}${"id": {"int":2}, "product": {"string":"Yağız Gülbahar"}, "quantity": {"int":1071}, "price": {"int":1453}}
```

**but when i put this to delete record on oracle it cant delete data just update columns as null**

```
{"id":2}${"id": null, "product": null , "quantity": null , "price": null }
```

how can I solve this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you need to produce a **Tombstone Record**. In Kafka deletion using JDBC Sink Connector works as follows:

> The connector can delete rows in a database table when it consumes a
> tombstone record, which is a Kafka record that has a non-null key and
> a null value. This behavior is disabled by default, meaning that any
> tombstone records will result in a failure of the connector, making it
> easy to upgrade the JDBC connector and keep prior behavior.
>
> Deletes can be enabled with `delete.enabled=true`, but only when the
> `pk.mode` is set to `record_key`. This is because deleting a row from the
> table requires the primary key be used as criteria.
>
> Enabling delete mode does not affect the `insert.mode`.

Also note that this kind of record will only be deleted only after `delete.retention.ms` milliseconds which currently defaults to 24 hours.

---

Therefore, try to reduce this configuration in your properties and see if it works. To do so, you need to run the following command:

```
 ./bin/kafka-topics.sh \
    --alter \
    --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
    --topic orders \
    --config retention.ms=100
```

---

Now once the configuration is done, all you need to do is to generate a message with non-null key and a null value. Note that the Kafka Console Consumer cannot be used in order to produce a null record as the user input is parsed as UTF-8.
Therefore,

```
{"id":2}${"id": null, "product": null , "quantity": null , "price": null }
```

is not an actual tombstone message.

You can however make use of [`kafkacat`](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat) but it does work only for JSON messages:

```
# Produce a tombstone (a "delete" for compacted topics) for key 
# "abc" by providing an empty message value which -Z interpretes as NULL:

echo "abc:" | kafkacat -b mybroker -t mytopic -Z -K:
```

but in your case this wouldn't work as you need to send Avro messages. Therefore, I would suggest to write a very simple Avro Producer in your favourite language so that you can actually send a tombstone message.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211589/discussion-on-answer-by-giorgos-myrianthous-why-record-cannot-get-deleted-using).